# Type {} is not assignable to type []

Tags: angular, typescript

I am a newbie in angular and am trying to get a list of properties referencing some previous examples I had already done. However I am given an error that ***type {} is not assignable to type `IProperty[]`*** on the line

> this.properties = properties;

. Any clarification to what might be going on

Below is the component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {IProperty} from './property';
import {ApiService} from '../api/api.service';

@Component({
    selector:'property',
    templateUrl: '.property.component.html'
})

export class PropertyComponent implements OnInit{
    errorMessage: any;
    properties:IProperty[] = [];

    constructor(private _apiService: ApiService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this._apiService.getProperties()
        .subscribe(properties => {
            this.properties = properties;
        },
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error)
    }

    private newFunction() {
        return this.properties;
    }
}
```

Property Interface

```
export interface IProperty
{
    propertyId: number;
    propertyName: string;
    price: number;
    description: string;
}
```

apiService

```
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

import {IProperty} from '../properties/property';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService{
    handleError: any;
    properties= [];
    constructor (private http: HttpClient){}

    getProperties(){
        return this.http.get<IProperty>('http://localhost:4200/properties').do(data => console.log('All: '+ JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError)
    }
}
```

Comment: i think your API (Back End) is returning an Object .. and you're trying to assign it to an array

Comment: Post the apiService. It's probably wrong.

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi this is a compilation error, not a runtime error. So it has nothing to do with what the backend returns.

Comment: @JBNizet But it does have everything to do with what the backend is declared as returning. Which may even be generated from what it actually returns.

Comment: @JBNizet Posted ApiService

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your service says that it returns **one** `IProperty`. The controller tries to assign that `IProperty` to an **array** of `IProperty`.

So, either the controller is right, and the service should use

```
this.http.get<Array<IProperty>>(...)
```

or the service is right, and the field should be declared as

```
property: IProperty = null;
```

I guess the former is what you actually want. You should aways declare what the service is supposed to return. The error would be much clearer:

```
getProperties(): Observable<Array<IProperty>> {
```

Answer (score 3):

Specify the type

```
properties:Array<IProperty> = [];

ngOnInit(){
    this._apiService.getProperties().subscribe(properties:Array<IProperty> => {
        this.properties = properties;
    },
    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your observable returns an object instead of an array. you need to change `properties` type as an object.

```
properties: IProperty = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your IProperty object might be a class and not an interface.
You want to make an array of object so you cant do this :

```
this.properties = properties;
```

I think your API return a json object so you have to parse it before :

```
this.properties = JSON.parse(properties)
```

OR if your API return simple IProperty you have to push it to the array :

```
this.properties.push(properties);
```